# Which deployed jar contains android.os.SystemClock?

Tags: java, android, command-line, jar

I am trying to run a simple command line java application on dalvikvm using the [these instructions](http://davanum.wordpress.com/2007/12/04/command-line-java-on-dalvikvm/). I am running as root so it is not a permissions issue.

Here is the application code:

```
import android.os.SystemClock;
/**
 * Command that sends key events to the device, either by their keycode, or by
 * desired character output.
 */
public class MWE {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(SystemClock.uptimeMillis());
    }
}
```

When I run this on dalvikvm, I get the following error message:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.os.SystemClock
        at MWE.main(MWE.java:8)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Here is the command that I run, which works for the normal Hello World version of the above application.

```
/system/bin/dalvikvm -Xbootclasspath:/system/framework/core.jar -classpath /data/local/tmp/MWE.jar MWE
```

My current conclusion is that `android.os.SystemClock` does not live inside `core.jar`. I have speculatively tried to add `framework.jar` and `framework-res.jar` as well, but I get the same error.

1. Which of the jars under `/system/framework` holds the class `android.os.SystemClock`?
2. In general, is there a place that has a class-to-jar mapping for deployed jars in Android?

Comment: It should be in android-*.jar?

Comment: Android.jar exists in multiple pieces on my phone. That jar is only in one piece on the computer.

Comment: Does it exist in your classpath? Am assuming its not.

Comment: Does what exist? I'm specifying class path manually using the command in the question

Comment: But i dont see it in question. I just see one jar /data/local/tmp/MWE.jar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On my device (HTC One M8) android.os.SystemClock is in /system/framework/framework3.jar. I believe framework is separated into multiple jars because of the 65k method limit on classes.dex. android.os.SystemClock may be in a different jar on different android devices.

Steps I used to find where android.os.SystemClock was located:

```
adb pull /system/framework/<filename>.jar
```

I then decompiled classes.dex to a jar with [DexToJar](https://code.google.com/p/dex2jar/) and viewed the packages inside the jar using [JD-GUI](https://code.google.com/p/innlab/downloads/detail?name=jd-gui-0.3.3.windows.zip&) (you could just open it as a ZIP file, jd-gui is not necessary and for windows only)

Comment: I'm on a Galaxy S4 and that class seems to only be in `framework.odex`. Any ideas on how to put an odex into the classpath?