# How do I add `odex` files to the classpath for dalvikvm?

Tags: java, android, dalvik

This question is a follow-up to my [earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26944851/which-deployed-jar-contains-android-os-systemclock/26944984#26944984).

Here is the same example from that question.

```
import android.os.SystemClock;
/**
 * Command that sends key events to the device, either by their keycode, or by
 * desired character output.
 */
public class MWE {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(SystemClock.uptimeMillis());
    }
}
```

After I looked around in my `/system/framework` directory, I discovered that the class `android.os.SystemClock` is defined in `framework.odex` on my phone. I naturally tried the following two command to try to access it.

```
/system/bin/dalvikvm -Xbootclasspath:/system/framework/core.jar -classpath /system/framework/framework.odex:/data/local/tmp/MWE.jar MWE
/system/bin/dalvikvm -Xbootclasspath:/system/framework/core.jar:/system/framework/framework.odex -classpath /data/local/tmp/MWE.jar MWE
```

However, both of them resulted in the same error message about not being able to find the class definition.

**How do I add such `odex` files to the classpath for dalvikvm?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried just:

```
/system/bin/dalvikvm -classpath /data/local/tmp/MWE.jar MWE
```

As far as I know, in this case it will pull in the boot classpath from the BOOTCLASSPATH environment variable, which should already contain core.jar and framework.jar.

However, I suspect that will actually result in an UnsatisfiedLinkError exception, because the JNI library that implements some of the native methods in SystemClock won't be loaded.

In that case, there's a [handy utility class](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base.git/+/android-4.4.4_r1/core/java/com/android/internal/util/WithFramework.java) available that should load the native libraries.

```
dalvikvm -classpath /data/local/tmp/MWE.jar com.android.internal.util.WithFramework MWE
```

Comment: This answer is beautifully complete. :)

Comment: Out of curiosity, did you end up having to use WithFramework to run it?

Comment: Yes, I did. The issue you predicted occurred and your solution fixed it.